# Check specific check box in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

i want to loop through each row of kendo grid and check the check box of specific rows only.here's what i have tried so far.

```
function LoadControllerGrid(list) {

        $("#controllerGrid1").kendoGrid({
            data Source: {
                type: "json",
                //    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetControllerList", "Account"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },

                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            'Id': { type: "string" },
                            'Name': { type: "string" },
                            'Description': { type: "string" },
                            'URL': { type: "string" },
                        },

                    },
                    data: 'data',
                    total: 'TotalCount'
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    //     HidePageLoader();

                },
                pageSize: 5,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                columnMenu: true
            },
            height: 300,
            groupable: false,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: 5000
            },
            columns: [{ template: '<input type="checkbox" id="#=Id#" class="gridCK" />', width: "35px" },
                      { field: "Description", title: "Actions" }, ]



        });

        var df = list;
        var grid = $("#controllerGrid1").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.tbody.find("input").closest("tr").each(function (index, row) {

            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
            for (var i = 0; i < df.length; i++)
            {

                if (df[i] == dataItem.Id) {

                    $("#controllerGrid1 tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.Id + "]").attr("checked");


        });


    }
```

can any one explain what did i do wrong?? and suggest if there are any alternative ways of doing this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

```
 var selected = $("#controllerGrid1 tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "]");
                        selected
                        .find("td:first input")
                        .attr("checked", true);
```

It works for me after adding above code instead of following,

```
 $("#controllerGrid1 tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.Id + "]").attr("checked");
```

Comment: Simplify your selection: `$("#controllerGrid1 tbody tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "] td:first input").attr("checked", true);`. No need that many `find`s...